# About sum of right-angled triangles'area and area of circle.

Tags: definite-integrals, triangles, circles

[the image shows right-angled triangles in semi-circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1M7D.png)

In Definite Integration, we know that area can be found by adding up the total area of each small divided parts.

So, base on the Definite Integration, we may say the area of circle is equal to 
$\sum^{n}_{k=1}(h_k)$

And we also know that $A_k=2r(h_k)(1/2)=rh_k$ while $A$ is refer to the right-angled triangle's area.

so that, $A_k(1/r)=h_k$

As a result this equation comes out with fixed position of diameter:

$\sum^{n}_{k=1}(h_k)=\pi r^2$

$\sum^{n}_{k=1}(A_k)(1/r)=\pi r^2$

$\sum^{n}_{k=1}(A_k)=\pi r^3$

I wish to know whether I am correct or not, thanks.

Comment: A little correction, sum $h_k$ = $\pi r^2/2$. I do not know if this is correct of not though

Comment: Thanks for your respond, but I am trying to use sum $h_k=π r^2$ for considering the heights of triangles in both sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrongly assumed that the sum of the heights $h_k$ is equal to the area of the circle. Area has dimensions $[L^2]$, so the area of the circle is actually the sum of the areas of the rectangular strips of height $h_k$ and infinitesimal base length $dx$.

$h_k=A_k/r\\\displaystyle\sum_1^\infty h_kdx=\sum_1^\infty\frac{A_kdx}r=\pi r^2$

Answer (score 0):

No, you are all wrong.

If you want to make a sum of areas of some triangles that is approximate to the area of the circle, these triangles *must not overlap.* On your linked picture the two triangles obviously overlap (have some common area), so the further discussion is pointless.

Comment: Thanks for the ans first. But what I want is to make a sum of heights of triangles that is approximate to the area of the circle (not the areas).

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I can see your point, so what you say is $\lim_{x \to 0}\sum^{n}_{k=1}(h_k)x=πr^2$?

Comment: Yes, $x\to0,n\to\infty$

Comment: It seems that @Students doesn't understand the concept of the **differential** $dx$ in the integral notation. Of course, it's not for a decorative purpose. It's meaning is that the value is infinitesimally small, i.e. $dx → 0$ but the sum of all these small values is constant – the full length of variable $x$ where integration is done (in case of a circle that sum is the diameter $2r$)